# Return tAda using Cardano-CLI

Tags: cardano-cli, testnet

I want to return test ADA to the [test faucet](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/testnet-faucet/). Is there an easy way to return the tAda? I'm using this documentation to create and submit a transaction to testnet: [How to create a metadata transaction using cardano-cli](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/transaction-metadata/how-to-create-a-metadata-transaction-cli)

```
cardano-cli query utxo --testnet-magic 1097911063 --address $(cat payment.addr)

cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in dfb99f8f103e56a856e04e087255dbaf402f3801acb71a6baf423a1054d3ccd5#0 \
--tx-out $(cat testfaucet.addr)+999825875 \
--metadata-json-file metadata.json \
--fee 174125 \
--out-file tx.draft

cardano-cli transaction sign \
--tx-body-file tx.draft \
--signing-key-file payment.skey \
--testnet-magic 1097911063 \
--out-file tx.signed 

cardano-cli transaction submit \
--tx-file tx.signed \
--testnet-magic 1097911063

Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 0 (fromList [])) (Value 1000000000 (fromList []))))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (BadInputsUTxO (fromList [TxIn (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "dfb99f8f103e56a856e04e087255dbaf402f3801acb71a6baf423a1054d3ccd5"}) 0]))))])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the [easiest way](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/) to return your tADA:

> When you have finished using your test tokens, please return them to the faucet so that other members of the community can use them. Please return your test tokens to this address:

addr_test1qqr585tvlc7ylnqvz8pyqwauzrdu0mxag3m7q56grgmgu7sxu2hyfhlkwuxupa9d5085eunq2qywy7hvmvej456flknswgndm3

Comment: Thank you, I'm wondering how to do this? I have the wallet address, but don't know how to send the tokens to the address.

Comment: The same way as tADA, but with fee...

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to set a `--ttl <SLOT NUMBER>` parameter for the `transaction build-raw` command